# passing the value from table to textbox in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to pass the value from table to text box in angularjs. value should be pass when i click 'pass the value' button. can anyone help me with this? 
my code is shared below:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.array = [{
      id:1,
      name: 'name1',
      address: 'address1'
      
    }, {
      id:2,
      name: 'name2',
      address: 'address2'
    }, {
      id:3,
      name: 'name3',
      address: 'address3'
    }];
  
  $scope.edit=function(id){
   
  };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller" class="container">
  <table class="table table-condensed">
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>address</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in array" >
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.address}}</td>
      <td><button ng-click="edit(item.id)">pass the value</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <form>
    name <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" />
    address <input type="text" ng-model="item.address"/>
  </form>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show your code rather than  screen shot ?

Comment: yeah, i shared my code above

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just passing the id, pass the whole item to the edit function:

```
<button ng-click="edit(item)">
```

Then you can set the item on scope to the passed item:

```
$scope.edit=function(item){
  $scope.item = item;
};
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9pwHS1V4lP2CbPhm3msC?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You should assign your index in a variable in click function. Like

```
<button ng-click=" newIndex = $index; ">pass the value</button>
```

And fetch this indexed value from array. Like

```
name <input type="text" ng-value="array[newIndex].name" />
address <input type="text" ng-value="array[newIndex].address"/>
```

Make sure to declare `newIndex` in your controller first. Like

```
$scope.newIndex = null;
```

Comment: doesn't seems working for me. can you share the working code for me?